# Angular 2 Emitting event to sibling Directive(Component)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

I was trying to emit an event from one component to other sibling component. I have tried @Output but it emits an event to parent component. suggest please.

Comment: See Cookbook topic [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).

Answer (score 1):

> 1 -  Use a **shared service**, or
>
> 2 - communicate **through the parent** - listen for the event in the parent
>   component then let parent do stuff on the sibling component.

The best way is to leverage the power of **Dependency Injection** and communicate through a ***shared/common service***.